# Unordered Map: Own Value Type Issue

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an user-defined class, which is supposed to be the value type of an unsorted_map. My problem is, that inserting is not working (already a static error when compiling with gcc 4.7).

My Class:

```
class bk_tree {

public:
    bk_point *root;
    DISTANCE_FUN metric;
    int max_depth;

    //assume words not empty
    bk_tree() {metric=NULL; root=NULL; max_depth = 0;}

    //rule of three
    bk_tree(const bk_tree& copy_this) {metric=copy_this.metric; root=copy_this.root; max_depth = copy_this.max_depth;}
    bk_tree& operator=(const bk_tree& copy_this) { metric=copy_this.metric; root=copy_this.root; max_depth = copy_this.max_depth; return *this; }
    ~bk_tree() { delete root; }

    bk_tree(unordered_set<string> *words, DISTANCE_FUN _metric);
    bk_tree(DISTANCE_FUN _metric) { metric = _metric; root = NULL; max_depth = 0;        
};
```

Code in order to create a map and insert:

```
 #include<tr/unordered_map>
 using namespace std;
 using namespace std::tr1;

 unordered_map<DocID, sigmod::bk_tree> *my_map = new unordered_map<DocID, sigmod::bk_tree>;
 sigmod::bk_tree my_value = sigmod::bk_tree(&words, sigmod::hamming_distance_metric);
 doc_bk_hamming->insert(make_pair(my_key, my_value));
```

Compilation (g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -fopenmp -fPIC -Wall -g -I. -I./include   -c -o ref_impl/core.o) Error:

```
ref_impl/core.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:42,
                 from ref_impl/../include/metric.h:5,
                 from ref_impl/core.cpp:29:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::is_convertible<const std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false>&, std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false> >’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits:116:12:   required from ‘struct std::__and_<std::is_convertible<const std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false>&, std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false> >, std::is_convertible<const bool&, bool> >’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:113:38:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits:1263:12: error: the value of ‘std::__is_convertible_helper<const std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false>&, std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false>, false>::value’ is not usable in a constant expression
/usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits:1258:70: note: ‘std::__is_convertible_helper<const std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false>&, std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false>, false>::value’ used in its own initializer
/usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits:1263:12: note: in template argument for type ‘bool’ 
/usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__and_<std::is_convertible<const std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false>&, std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false> >, std::is_convertible<const bool&, bool> >’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:113:38:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/type_traits:116:12: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::is_convertible<const std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false>&, std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, sigmod::bk_tree>, false, false> >’
```

Comment: `root=copy_this.root;` You are copying the value of the pointer. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Your copy constructor and copy assignment operator are broken. After the operation, both objects will have the same pointer and both destructors will attempt to delete it.

Comment: The code you pasted is fine. The issue is in code you haven't pasted.

Comment: DocID:
typedef unsigned int DocID;

Comment: Ok, thanks - so if I leave the destructor empty, then I will have a memory leak. But the compilation error remains... If i comment out the "doc_bk_hamming->insert(make_pair(my_key, my_value));" then no errors occur...

Comment: @user575915 Are you sure, that DocID is unsigned int? Since this works fine http://liveworkspace.org/code/2eLFd5$11

Comment: I agree with @DavidSchwartz. Still no compiler error from http://ideone.com/ohF59z

Answer (score 1):

Is the DocID type hashable?  This is necessary for the key-type of an unordered_map and this is what the compailer complains about.  On the other hand, DocID sounds like it would support an order, why not use a map, which is implemented as a binary search tree?

Also, your copy constructor and copy assignment operator are broken. They copy the pointer and then the original object and the copy both think they own the resource.  If one of them is destructed the resource is deleted, leading to a double-free when the other object is destructed.

Comment: typedef unsigned int DocID. So it is supposed to be hashable? I fixed the destructor and the error remains :(

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of missing information that prevents us to give you a proper answer. For instance, what is `doc_bk_hamming`? You allocate and `unordered_map` and assign its address to the pointer `my_map`. However, you are inserting the `(my_key, my_value)` pair into a map pointed by `doc_bk_hamming` which we don't see.